I want change Decimal field Precision value dynamically
I want change Decimal field Precision value dynamically for each grid row.
I have try it with field Selecting and with custom attribute but its not working

For this purpose you can play around with FieldSelecting event. It is purposed for "cooking" visual presentation of the field in Acumatica. Below goes code sample of how this method is used for conversion of decimal value to word presentation, i.e. 1921.14 would be converted to "One thousand nine hundred twenty one and fourteen"
/// <summary>
/// Converts Decimal value to it's word representation (English only) one way only<br/>
/// For example, 1921.14 would be converted to "One thousand nine hundred twenty one and fourteen".<br/>
/// Should be placed on the string field   
/// <example>
/// [ToWords(typeof(APPayment.curyOrigDocAmt))]
/// </example>
/// </summary>
public class ToWordsAttribute : PXEventSubscriberAttribute, IPXFieldSelectingSubscriber
{
    protected string _DecimalField = null;
    protected short? _Precision = null;
    public ToWordsAttribute(Type DecimalField)
    {
        _DecimalField = DecimalField.Name;
    }

    public ToWordsAttribute(short Precision)
    {
        _Precision = Precision; ;
    }

    public virtual void  FieldSelecting(PXCache sender, PXFieldSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.ReturnState = PXStringState.CreateInstance(e.ReturnState, 255, null, _FieldName, null, null, null, null, null, false, null);

        object DecimalVal;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_DecimalField))
        {
            DecimalVal = sender.GetValue(e.Row, _DecimalField);
            sender.RaiseFieldSelecting(_DecimalField, e.Row, ref DecimalVal, true);
        }
        else
        {
            DecimalVal = PXDecimalState.CreateInstance(e.ReturnValue, (short)_Precision, _FieldName, false, 0, Decimal.MinValue, Decimal.MaxValue);
        }

        if (DecimalVal is PXDecimalState)
        {
            if (((PXDecimalState)DecimalVal).Value == null)
            {
                e.ReturnValue = string.Empty;
                return;
            }

            e.ReturnValue = LangEN.ToWords((decimal)((PXDecimalState)DecimalVal).Value, ((PXDecimalState)DecimalVal).Precision);
        }
    }
}

